# WebSphere Portal 6.1 puma problems

Tags: user-management, websphere-portal

I installed 6.1.0.1 WebSphere Portal, updated it to the last recommended fix packs (WAS including). Configured user registry with LDAP server (Tivoli Directory Server 6.0).

Portal applications like group/user managements work with users correctly. The same is correct for admin console's Manage Users/Manage Groups.

But when I run such code in my application:

```
String dn = "cn=agsgroup,cn=groups,dc=egov2g,dc=kz";
String id = "cn";

Context ctx = new InitialContext();
PumaHome service = (PumaHome) ctx.lookup(PumaHome.JNDI_NAME);
PumaProfile pp = service.getProfile();
PumaLocator pl = service.getLocator();

Group group = pl.findGroupByIdentifier(dn);
Map map = pp.getAttributes(group, Arrays.asList(new String[] {id}));
```

**I always get a MemberNotFoundException**

```
com.ibm.portal.puma.MemberNotFoundException: EJPSG0002E: Requested Member does not exist.cn=agsgroup,cn=groups,dc=egov2g,dc=kz
```

dn is 100% correct. The same code works on production and another my server.
But on new installations and servers of other developers there is the described problem.

I compared wimconfig.xml files on working and nonworking servers and couldn't find any differences.

Looking for any ideas

**UPDATE**
The code runs correctly in the portlet. So it looks that when I run it without portlet context puma is not initialized correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved.

It's necessary to provide access right for some virtual resources: USERS and USER_GROUPS.
It's done in Portal Admin Panel: Access -> Resource Permissions -> Virtual Resources -> Users (User groups)

Give appropriate permisions to the resources (in my case all permissions)

Comment: Please also ACCEPT your answer!